# Suggested Contact Folder

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to retrieve users who have 'Suggested Contacts' as a folder in their email, and then delete it.

I have tried with Microsoft Graph, but to no avail, using the string `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$Mailbox/mailFolders/?includeHiddenFolders=true`, so this route is not viable if I cannot retrieve the folder ID.

The alternative is to use `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $Mailbox| Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Suggested Contacts' } | Select Name, FolderSize, ItemsinFolder` to verify that the user has the desired folder, but there is no specific command to delete it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Because that folder has a folderclass of IPF.Contact you won't be able to get it in the MailFolder endpoint. Also because its parent folder is the Non IPM Subtree root it won't appears in the ContactsFolder endpoint unless you know what the folderId is. So getting this folder just using the Graph is pretty hard. As you found you can get the Folder using Get-MailboxFolderStatistics  (or Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics) which will return and FolderId you can then convert that to a Graphid using /translateExchangeIds and then use that id in the ContactsFolder endpoint so something like this should work (as long as you have applications permission or "Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared" as a scope in the PowerShell Graph SDK)

```html
function Get-SuggestedContactsFolder{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
  param( 
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $MailboxName = ""
  )  
    Process{     
      $exofolder = Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $MailboxName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Suggested Contacts'}
      $graphid = Invoke-TranslateId -MailboxName $MailboxName -Base64FolderIdToTranslate $exofolder.FolderId
      return  Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method Get -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailboxName/contactfolders/$graphid
  }
}



function Invoke-TranslateId{
  [CmdletBinding()] 
  param( 
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false)]
    [String]
    $Base64FolderIdToTranslate = "",
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false)]
    [String]
    $HexEntryId = "",
    [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $MailboxName = ""

  )  
  Process {
    
    if(![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Base64FolderIdToTranslate)){
      $HexEntryId = [System.BitConverter]::ToString([Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64FolderIdToTranslate)).Replace("-", "").Substring(2)  
      $HexEntryId = $HexEntryId.SubString(0, ($HexEntryId.Length - 2))
    }
    $FolderIdBytes = [byte[]]::new($HexEntryId.Length / 2)
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt $HexEntryId.Length; $i += 2) {      $FolderIdBytes[$i / 2] = [convert]::ToByte($HexEntryId.Substring($i, 2), 16)
    }

    $FolderIdToConvert = [Convert]::ToBase64String($FolderIdBytes).Replace("==",2).Replace("=",1).Replace('+','-').Replace('/','_')
    
    $ConvertRequest = @"
{
    "inputIds" : [
      "$FolderIdToConvert"
    ],
    "sourceIdType": "entryId",
    "targetIdType": "restId"
  }
"@
    Write-verbose $ConvertRequest
    $ConvertResult = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method POST -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailboxName/translateExchangeIds -Body $ConvertRequest
    return $ConvertResult.Value.targetId
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Glen, Thank you for your reply
I get two types of errors: `Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpServerUtility]`
The second, I don't know what it could be
 `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Cache-Control: private Transfer-Encoding: chunked  {"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidRequest","message":"The OData request is not
     | supported."}}`

Comment: I guess your using Powershell 7, I've update the script to be ps7 and it works okay for me, the second error probably just a fall through error from formatting issues of the id. The Kibana based SDK doesn't really give good error messages, if you still get error trying running with the -Verbose switch